# Issue in Mysql DB connection with ruby using gem 'dbi'

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, dbi

```
    gem 'dbi'
require 'dbi'


begin
con = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'root', '1234'
puts con.get_server_info
rs = con.query 'SELECT VERSION()'
puts rs.fetch_row    

rescue Mysql::Error => e
puts e.errno
puts e.error

ensure
con.close if con
end
```

and it shows error like this.

> rescue in ': uninitialized constant Mysql (NameError).

Help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
require 'dbi'


begin
 con = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:localhost","username", "password")
puts con.get_server_info
rs = con.query 'SELECT VERSION()'
puts rs.fetch_row    

rescue Mysql::Error => e
puts e.errno
puts e.error

ensure
con.close if con
end
```

try this

Comment: not working still getting this error.                                                       rescue in <main>': uninitialized constant Mysql (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

you are not using MySQL bu the `dbi` gem...

```
dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:Mysql:localhost', 'testuser', 'testpwd')
sth = dbh.prepare('SELECT VERSION()')
sth.execute
while row=sth.fetch do
    p row
end
```

try doing it this way..